# Use of eval function

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I know that the function eval executes the string(in the parameter) without the quotes .So what I was just trying was that

```
x=eval("4*5")  #this works
eval("x=4*5")  #but this doesn't
```

Please tell where I am wrong!

Comment: While it's fine to be curious about this, using eval or exec is pretty much always the wrong approach to solving a problem. If you tell us what you're trying to do in a larger context, we can tell you a better way to do it.

Comment: eval take an expression as arguments.

Comment: ya I got it,Thanks . I was just trying to know the use of eval function . I thought whatever is written in the argument is executed as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
exec('x=4*5')
```

eval evaluates only expressions not assignments.

Answer (score 1):

`4*5` is an **expression**, it has a value of `20`.

`x=4*5` is not an expression and it doesn't have a value. It's a **statement**, meaning it performs an action.

Answer (score 1):

`eval()` runs its string parameter as a python expression. It evaluates the value of that expression. It cannot work with assignments or other statements that are not expressions.

Answer (score 1):

`eval` function has the following structure:

```
eval(expression, globals=None, locals=None)
```

The expression argument is parsed and evaluated as a Python expression. It is actually a string expression rather than a assignment.

Ref: [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)